# Write hello world doesn't render in view in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I just started to learn magento. I just made custom module of Hello World.Action is workin in controller's action but it doesn't render in temple My namespace is Company and Module name is Web.
 
My module Fle - Company_Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Web>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Company_Web>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Here is my controller - IndexController.

```
<?php

class Company_Web_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {    
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}

?>
```

My config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Web>
            <version>1.6.0.0.2</version>
        </Company_Web>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <web>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Web</module>
                    <frontName>web</frontName>
                </args>
            </web>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <web>
                    <file>web.xml</file>
                </web>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

This is my layout file. -web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <web_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="web" template="web/web.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </web_index_index>
</layout>
```

This is my view file

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Can anyone please tell me what is i am missing ? Why it doesn't rendering in view file. I also disabled all the cache.Still it is not working.

Comment: Did you register your module in `app/etc/modules` folder? if yes, post that code too.

Comment: I just added my module file in comments.

Comment: replace `<web>` with `<company_web>` (_small letters_) everywhere in layout file.

Comment: It worked fine for me. You must be placing files at some wrong place.
please have a look at this tutorial for understanding the directory structure 
http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/

Comment: I am using magento's latest version - 1.9.0.1. I tried your given module. It also doesn't work for me.

Comment: Its working fine for version 1.9.0.1  Please clear your magento cache and check again. The url must be - http://localhost/magento/index.php/web

Comment: I cleared all the cache. Yes my url is same as per your comments. I chekced in my index controller in action i write 'hello' and die. And it's working in that action but doesn't rendering.

Comment: I have shared directory structure in my answer. Please check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is directory structure for the module -

```
\app\etc\modules\Company_Web.xml

\app\code\local\Company\Web\etc\config.xml

\app\code\local\Company\Web\controllers\IndexController.php

\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\web.xml

\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\web\web.phtml
```

Please check with your path if it works.

Comment: Thanks dude. It's working now. I put my view file in \app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\web.xml instead of \app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\web.xml. Thanks for you efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Your module is perfectly run on my computer. please check all files you placed in right place.
Also check folder name. it is case sensitive.

Comment: I checked my all folder that are file. I checked it comes in index action. But doesn't rendering

Comment: Have you checked my code in magento's version 1.9.0.1 ?

Comment: Yes i have tested it on magento 1.9.0.1 and it work perfectly. I think you put your layout web.xml file and template file web.phtml in default/default directory. it must be put in app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\web.xml  and  app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\web\web.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush cash and check if files are in the right (package and template) folder.

Comment: #Gerard. i tried as per your comments.But still it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please flush the cache and if compilation is enabled, `System >> Tools >> Compilation` please `run compilation` again.

Comment: I disabled my all the cache.So i don't need to do that.